# XML Keeps Selecting The Same Record

Tags: xml, xslt

So recently I've been trying to extract the simplest data possible however XSL keeps selecting the first record all the time.

Now I have tested the select="//student", it successfully selects all the data but when it comes to displaying it in the table, it messes up I think

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<school>
 <class unitId="3311">
 <className>English</className>
 <studentList>
 <student id="1001">Lisa Simpson</student>
 <student id="1002">Barney Rubble</student>
 <student id="1003">Donald Duck</student>
 </studentList>
 </class>
</school>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Students</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">STUDENT</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//student">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../student"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What I Keep Running Into**
[image]

Comment: Could `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` do anything more useful inside your `td`? I'm not overly familiar with XSLT, but what you wrote looks to me like "Select all `student` subnodes, then go to their parent and select the first `student` subnode". Which is not what you want - you want the node you just selected, whose relative path is `.`.

Comment: Sounds like there was only one child, or the child elements you were looking at were all alike. Glad your problem's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

Also it is better to specifically select the parent node in the for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/school/studentList/student">
[...]
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath, `../student`, is the problem. For every `student` in the document(`//student`) you are going to its parent and selecting the children `student`s. Using `xsl:value-of` you will get only the first value as XSLT1.0 selects only the first element's value.

Change it to 
`<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

so that it selects the current value for every `student`.